# Django : SQLite Database is Locked when I build like feature on my home page

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am implementing Like functionality in Web application. Idea is Simple to List number of Post(Blogs) on Home page and Add a Like Button to each post(Blog). It works fine when I build it with normal

```
<form action='{% url target %}' method='POST'>
```

But when I implemented this with AJAX call It only allows me to like or dislike a particular post(blog) a single time.i.e One I liked a Post for first time it works, also when I dislike the same Post It works fine, But when I again Like that Post it throws an `django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked`

Also, when I like same post multiple(4 to 5) times it respond in a weird way. I goes in Loop of liking and dislikig post.

like_section.html

```
<form id="like-form{{ post.id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" id="{{ post.id }}btn" name="like" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn upvote">Like</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    {% for like in post.likes.all %}
      {% if like != user %}
        dislikingPost("{{ post.id }}btn");
      {% else %}
        likingPost("{{ post.id }}btn");
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}



    $(document).ready(function(event){
      $(document).on('click', '#{{ post.id }}btn', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        pk = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
          data: {
            'id': pk,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
          },

          success:function(response){
            $('#like-form{{ post.id }}').html(response['form'])
            // $('#{{ post.id }}btn').style.color = 'green';
          }, error: function(er, e){
            console.log(er.responseText);
          }
        });
      });
    });

    </script>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def like_post(request):
    all_posts = Posts.objects.all()
    print("Insisde Like Post")
    print('ID coming from form is', request.POST.get('id'))
    post = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=request.POST.get('id'))  # for AJAX call
    context = {
        'all_posts': all_posts,
        'post': post
    }
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)                 # Liking The Post
        print("DisLiking the post")
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        print("Liking the post")
    if request.is_ajax():
        print('Hey its an AJAX calls')    # TEsting AJAX request
        html = render_to_string('like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Note:
1. I am beginner in AJAX.
2. I know SQLite can not handle redundant calls, But why it was working before without AJAX calls.
3. I am not providing models.py and complete template of home page and I don't think they are required.

Comment: I can provide you the solution to unlock it, as you already know `SQLite` can't handle multiple query execution simultaneously.

Comment: @ans2human whats the Solution??

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was not with the Django code. It was ajax call which was triggering Database more then one time on a single Button Click.

Adding `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` below `event.preventDefault();` in ajax call works perfect